# Qué tipo de dato representa data en este algoritmo?

Tags: python, encriptación

Muy buen día para todos, estoy haciendo mi tésis basada en encriptación de datos y quiero probar este código:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes

key = get_random_bytes(16)
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_EAX)
ciphertext, tag = cipher.encrypt_and_digest(data)

file_out = open("encrypted.bin", "wb")
[ file_out.write(x) for x in (cipher.nonce, tag, ciphertext) ]
file_out.close()
```

Quisiera saber qué tipo de dato es "data", pues cuando no pongo nada me sale error y cuando pongo un string, también me sale error.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y que dice la documentacion?

Comment: Una cadena de bytes, se representa con una `b` delante de un string, es decir `b"algo"` o invocando al método `.encode()` de un string

Answer (score 0):

La documentación está disponible en [PyCryptodome](https://www.pycryptodome.org/en/latest/src/introduction.html)

```
 encrypt_and_digest(plaintext, output=None)

    Perform encrypt() and digest() in one go.
    Parameters: plaintext (bytes) – the last piece of plaintext to encrypt
    Keyword Arguments:
        output (bytes/bytearray/memoryview) – the pre-allocated buffer where the ciphertext must be stored (as opposed to being returned).
    Returns:    a tuple with two items

        the ciphertext, as bytes
        the MAC tag, as bytes

    The first item becomes None when the output parameter specified a location for the result.
```

Entonces, `data` es aquello que quieres procesar, el texto original.

Dado que Python maneja los textos como Unicode, debes previamente transformarlos a bytes, usando la función `encode()`

```
texto_en_bytes = texto_original.encode()
texto_cifrado, tag = encrypt_and_digest(texto_en_bytes)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, estaré viendo la documentación, cualquier cosa comento por acá